# How to customize the Print Invoice/Memo report on the "Invoice and Memos" screen AR301000

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Can you help me find the event that allows me to customize the `Print Invoice / Memo` button?

Invoices and memos:

[image: Invoices and Memos]

I have tried to look for the method in this list and I do not know which one I should use.

Customize Invoice and Memos:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That action is running the "Invoice/Memo"(AR641000) printed form, if you want to customize the report you can edit AR641000 report.
If you want to change the report which will be printed you need to change the Automation Steps settings for the Report Action shown below:
[image]

Comment: I need to insert data into a table when I click on the "Print Invoice / Memo" button.

Comment: @Josediazugarte can you please add to the question what you need to write, where you need to write and why you want to write that data? There is no easy way to write some custom data on clicking this action, so maybe we will try to find another way to implement what you need.